# How to create following string with array in it?

Tags: php, url

I have an array from a $_GET say

```
Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 4
        )
```

for which i am using this while loop to create a string:

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($_GET)) {

          $get_url .= $key . '=' . rawurlencode(stripslashes($value)) . '&amp;';

      }
```

Now if i get an array from $_GET say like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => pid
    [1] => gid
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 4
        )

)
```

then in this case what could be the possible changes be done to while loop so that I can avoid the result like this **http://www.example.com/shopping_cart.php?0=pid&1=gid&2=Array** in url when i use this to redirect it.
I want the url to display the values properly..not like "**2=Array**".. how can i do this?

> **EDIT**

Thanks Folks for the help, but I cannot introduce new function neither I can replace the while loop with for loop, I would be very thankfull if you can help me in re-editing the given WHILE Loop...

> **EDIT 2**

I am using `header(location:$get_url)` for redirecting to created url, is this the problem of display of "2=Array" in url?

> **EDIT 3**

functions used to build query, NOTE: THESE FUNCTIONS ARE INBUILT FUNCTION OF osCommerce

I still changed one of it by introducing the foreach loop into it see below the use and function definition:

```
function tep_redirect($url) {
    if ( (strstr($url, "\n") != false) || (strstr($url, "\r") != false) ) { 
      tep_redirect(tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, '', 'NONSSL', false));
    }

    if ( (ENABLE_SSL == true) && (getenv('HTTPS') == 'on') ) { // We are loading an SSL page
      if (substr($url, 0, strlen(HTTP_SERVER . DIR_WS_HTTP_CATALOG)) == HTTP_SERVER . DIR_WS_HTTP_CATALOG) { // NONSSL url
        $url = HTTPS_SERVER . DIR_WS_HTTPS_CATALOG . substr($url, strlen(HTTP_SERVER . DIR_WS_HTTP_CATALOG)); // Change it to SSL
      }
    }

    $url =  str_replace("&amp;", "&", $url);

    header('Location: ' . $url);

    tep_exit();
  }
```

=========================

```
   function tep_href_link($page = '', $parameters = '', $connection = 'NONSSL', $add_session_id = true, $search_engine_safe = true) {
        global $request_type, $session_started, $SID, $spider_flag;

        if (!tep_not_null($page)) {
          die('</td></tr></table></td></tr></table><br><br><font color="#ff0000">' . TEP_HREF_LINK_ERROR1);
        }

        if ($connection == 'NONSSL') {
          $link = HTTP_SERVER . DIR_WS_HTTP_CATALOG;
        } elseif ($connection == 'SSL') {
          if (ENABLE_SSL == true) {
            $link = HTTPS_SERVER . DIR_WS_HTTPS_CATALOG;
          } else {
            $link = HTTP_SERVER . DIR_WS_HTTP_CATALOG;
          }
        } else {
          die('</td></tr></table></td></tr></table><br><br><font color="#ff0000">' . TEP_HREF_LINK_ERROR2);
        }

        if (tep_not_null($parameters)) {
          while ( (substr($parameters, -5) == '&amp;') ) $parameters = substr($parameters, 0, strlen($parameters)-5);
          $link .= $page . '?' . tep_output_string($parameters);
          $separator = '&amp;';
        } else {
          $link .= $page;
          $separator = '?';
        }


        // if session is not started or requested not to add session, skip it
        if ( ($add_session_id == true) && ($session_started == true) ){

          // if cookies are not set and not forced, then add the session info incase the set cookie fails 
          if ( ! isset($_COOKIE[tep_session_name()]) && (SESSION_FORCE_COOKIE_USE == 'False') ) {
            $_sid = tep_session_name() . '=' . tep_session_id();

          // if we are chaning modes and cookie domains differ, we need to add the session info
          } elseif ( HTTP_COOKIE_DOMAIN . HTTP_COOKIE_PATH != HTTPS_COOKIE_DOMAIN . HTTPS_COOKIE_PATH
                     &&
                     (
                       ( $request_type == 'NONSSL' && $connection == 'SSL' && ENABLE_SSL == true )
                       ||
                       ( $request_type == 'SSL' && $connection == 'NONSSL' )
                     )
                   ) {
            $_sid = tep_session_name() . '=' . tep_session_id();
          }

        }

        if (isset($_sid) && !$spider_flag) {
          $link .= $separator . tep_output_string($_sid);
        }

        return $link;
      }
```

===========================

```
function tep_get_all_get_paramtrs($exclude_array = '') {
    global $HTTP_GET_VARS;

    if (!is_array($exclude_array)) $exclude_array = array();

    $get_url = '';
    if (is_array($HTTP_GET_VARS) && (sizeof($HTTP_GET_VARS) > 0)) 
    {
      reset($HTTP_GET_VARS);
      foreach($HTTP_GET_VARS as $key => $a)
      {
        if(is_array($a))
        {
            foreach($a as $k => $v)
            {
                $get_url[] = $key . '[]' . '=' . rawurlencode(stripslashes($v));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $get_url[] = $key . '=' . rawurlencode(stripslashes($a));
        }
      }

   /*   while (list($key, $value) = each($HTTP_GET_VARS)) 
      {
      if(!is_array($value))
      {
        if ( (strlen($value) > 0) && ($key != tep_session_name()) && ($key != 'error') && (!in_array($key, $exclude_array)) && ($key != 'x') && ($key != 'y') ) 
        {
          $get_url .= $key . '=' . rawurlencode(stripslashes($value));
        }
      }
      else
      {

      if ( (strlen($value) > 0) && ($key != tep_session_name()) && ($key != 'error') && (!in_array($key, $exclude_array)) && ($key != 'x') && ($key != 'y') ) 
        {
          $get_url .= preg_replace('/#\d/','[]',http_build_query($value,$key.'#'));
        }
     /*     while(list($key1, $value1) = each($value))
        {
            if ( (strlen($value1) > 0) && ($key1 != tep_session_name()) && ($key1 != 'error') && (!in_array($key1, $exclude_array)) && ($key1 != 'x') && ($key1 != 'y') ) 
            {
              $get_url .= $key1 . '=' . rawurlencode(stripslashes($value1));
            }
        }*/
     /* }
      }*/
      $get_url .=  '&amp;';
    }

    return $get_url;
  }
```

========================

```
tep_redirect(tep_href_link($goto, tep_get_all_get_paramtrs($parameters)));
```

here $parameters is an array with two values which doesnt have any resemblence with url display logic

Comment: I believe there's a PHP built-in function that does that, http_build_query. Would that help?

Comment: What's difficult about simply replacing it with the native function?

Comment: it will be changes for many things which are coded accordingly.. and we are unaware of those effects

Comment: Sounds like the right time to introduce [UnitTesting](http://www.phpunit.de/).

Comment: Now how does this relates to my query? Dont even find any Humour in it... :(

Comment: My comment wasn't intended to be funny. Write some tests for that code to ensure the code works as it should. Then replace the `while` with `http_build_query`. Run the test again. If it fails, you know you did something wrong. If it passes, you have successfully refactored clumsy code.

Comment: 2 notes. You should urlencode a ray as well as a value. You should not use stripslashes here.

Comment: Thanx Col. but could u throw some light on why does it gives me "2=Array" inspite of using below of the foreach and a while loop as answer from below?

Comment: because it *always* says `Array` when you try to print an array. What other result you expect from `print $array;` and why?

Comment: if you want to do it manually, you will need to implement a **recursion**. I doubt it is what you want

Comment: Col. Pls see the updated Question with functions I have used in it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an url from a multi-dimensional array, you should use a recursion, or just the built-in php function, which results the same as the function I created [http-build-query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) (just as Maurice Kherlakian said). It's the easiest way for doing this.

**A recursive function example:**

```
function URLfromArray($array,$url = "")
{

    foreach($array as $key => $val)
    {
        if(is_array($val))
        {
            $url = URLfromArray($val,$url);
        }
        else
        {
            $url .= $key."=".$val."&";
        }
    }

    return $url;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

did you consider using http_build_query() or http_build_url()?

Answer (score 0):

You could check with [`is_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) and use [`implode`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) or just loop through the array if you want different keys such as 2_0, 2_1.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the value is an array, then recurse or iterate over it...

```
if (is_array($value)
{
    // process this array
}
else
{
   // normal path
   $get_url .= $key . '=' . rawurlencode(stripslashes($value)) . '&amp;';
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

Answer (score 0):

header() has nothing to do with your problem.
you just fail to build proper query string
And I wonder why your problem is still persists despite of all these http_build_query() you've been told already

Comment: I have updated the question  with three functions I am using to build a query, these functions are inbuilt osCommerce functions.. plss guide me

Answer (score -1):

You could use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to serialize the array into a single string and urlencode that resulting string, on the receiving end you would then use urldecode and [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).